# filecontents environment cannot change temporary files

Tags: filecontents

```
\begin{filecontents}{exampleclass.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{exampleclass}
    \DeclareOption{testoption}{\PassOptionsToClass{a5paper}{article}}
    \ProcessOptions\relax
    \LoadClass{article}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[testoption]{exampleclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

If I compile the above code (using XeLaTeX, TeXStudio, Windows) I get a nicely typeset A5-paper article. If next I change `a5paper` to `twocolumn` and compile again, nothing changes. I get the warning

```
File `exampleclass.cls' already exists on the system.
```

So I suppose there is some temporary `cls.`-file created which cannot be edited. How do I change this behaviour?

Comment: it's just created in the current directory, you can simply delete it if you have edited the content and want latex to re-write it.

Comment: @David Carlisle Ah ok, and since I had not saved my above document, TeXStudio indeed created temporary files.

Comment: oh so texstudio saves the file somewhere strange and runs latex there?  A bit strange but OK:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## LaTeX after 2019-10-01

The LaTeX kernel has extended its `filecontents` environment to support an optional argument, see [LaTeX News, Issue 30, LaTeX releas 2019-10-01](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews30.pdf).

If the option `force` or its alias `overwrite` is specified, the environment follows the behavior of package `filecontents` and allows that the file is overwritten.

Example (without package `filecontents`):

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{exampleclass.cls}
...
\end{filecontents}
```

## LaTeX before 2019-10-01

Package `filecontents` allows the overwriting of files:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{exampleclass.cls}
...
\end{filecontents}
```

### LaTeX kernel

The original environment `filecontents` from the LaTeX kernel is documented in `source2e`:

> The environment `filecontents` is intended for passing the contents of
> pack              ages, options, or other files along with a document
> in a single file. It has one               argument, which is the name
> of the file to create. If that file already exists maybe only in the
> current directory if the OS supports a notion of a "current directory"
> or "default directory") then nothing happens (except for an
> information message) and the body of the environment is bypassed.
> Otherwise, the body of the environment is written verbatim to the file
> name given as the first argument, together with some comments about
> how it was produced.
>
> The environment is allowed only before `\documentclass` to ensure that
> all packages or options necessary for this particular run are present
> when needed. The begin and end tags should each be on a line by
> itself. There is also a star-form; this does not write extra comments
> into the file.

### Package

Package [`filecontents`](https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) lifts the restrictions:

- It allows the overwriting.
- The place for the environment is not restricted to before `\documentclass`. It can also be placed in the preamble or after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Package filecontents refuses to be loaded (log says "Package filecontents Warning: This package is obsolete. Disabling it"). Is there any workaround?

Comment: @LucasSoares I have updated the answer for the new `filecontents` environment of the LaTeX kernel 2019-10-01.